# Function .__ proto__ why not an instance of Function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This code

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(Function.__proto__);
// prints: "[object Function]"
```

implies that `Function.__ proto__` is of type `Function`.
Whereas this code

```
Function.__proto__.__proto__ == Function.prototype
// false
Function.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype
// true
```

suggests that it's not an instance of `Function`, but rather an instance of `Object`.

How can that be explained.

Comment: [The Function prototype object: \[...\] has a \[\[Prototype\]\] internal slot whose value is %Object.prototype%.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object)

Comment: `Function.__proto__ == Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) == Function.prototype`

Comment: And of course `Function.prototype` cannot inherit from itself, it must inherit from something else like `Object.prototype`.